# conditional formatting excel: identifying and coloring duplicate value cells within a single row (row only) for an entire set of data

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, format

I'm trying to figure out how one can conditionally format (or create a macro if necessary) a single row to identify cells with duplicate values within the columns for that row (and highlight these yellow) and then drag using the format painter for an entire dataset (100+ rows) so that all duplicates are identified that are row specific ( does not take in to account duplicates cell values within different rows). I have manually done the below attached example. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

example of duplicates, but manually done
[image: example of duplicates, but manually done]

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula,

```
=countif($a1:$f1, a1)>1
```

[image]